# What is the equivalent of "flip through" for movies?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

According to [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/flip_through), **flip through** means:

> Look or search quickly through (a volume or a collection of papers).

Is there a similar phrase that can be used for a movie? To get the main idea or search for something quickly, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean to view a film or video rapidly by jumping from point to point, you can "fast-forward" through it. With digital media you can move forward using the mouse, keyboard, remote control etc and often select a multiple of the normal speed e.g. 2x 4x etc. I would still use fast forward to denote this action.

> fast-forward
>
> verb ​
>
> If you fast-forward a recording, or if it
>   fast-forwards, you make it play at very high speed so that you get to
>   the end or a later part more quickly:
>
> I hate this song - I'll fast-forward to the next one.
>
> The tape jammed while I was fast-forwarding it.

[Fast-forward (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fast-forward)

Comment: What about *skim through* or *skip through*?

Comment: They would work too.

Comment: An anarchic holdover from the days when **fast-forwarding** (or **rewinding**) a physical tape was the *only* option  :)

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, "flip through" will work just fine.

> He **flipped through** his movie collection, but the one he wanted wasn't in the DVD case.

The phrase is also commonly used for TV channels.

> She **flipped through** the channels, looking for something to watch.

---

You can also use the word [**browse**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/browse?s=t), if what you're wanting is "to look through multiple movies."

> I **browsed** Netflix yesterday to see if they had it yet.

---

Finally, you might prefer the word [**scan,**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/scan?s=t) which can mean "to look through multiple movies" or "to look through a single movie (for a person or scene)".

> I know Matt Damon is in this movie, **scan through** it yourself if you don't believe me!

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the question, at least in the first part.  I expect **scan** is what OP is looking for.  I suggest editing to put that first, and then give the other suggestions after.

Answer (score 1):

You can **scan** a listing of movies, or as PlutoThePlanet says in that answer, **scan through** such a listing.